# restore script variable date and time

Tags: t-sql, restore

Goodafternoon,

i am looking for a variable for the date and time. I have several backups in one directory and want to restore the latest to a another server. Is there a variable i can use in my script?

```
test_db_201508**162300**.BAK
```

the script

```
restore database [test]
from disk = N'R:\testserver\test_db_201508**162300.BAK**'
with file = 1
    ,move N'test' to N'E:\Databases\test.mdf'
    ,move N'test_log' to N'F:\Logfiles\test_1.ldf'
    ,NOUNLOAD
    ,REPLACE
    ,STATS = 10
go
```

Comment: Look at [my answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107392/8783). Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: this does not work ):

Comment: what does not work ? Did you try ? what error are you getting ?

Comment: this is what i get for error